Correct dialogue path when captured by V
When V captures you, there’s a very long sequence of dialogue options you can take. If you get it wrong, V shoots you and time rewinds, starting the conversation over.
What’s the correct dialogue path(s)?

There's nothing wrong with it. You are supposed to be killed and let the time rewind, because each time you die you'll learn something from previous dialogues, unlocking different options to choose.
A bit like Life is Strange.
Here's a video walkthrough if you still struggle.
